# Returning a default grade from a score value

Tags: php, mysql, html, loops

Here is my problem. I upload a csv file containing two columns (student Number and Score). But when i form an HTML table from the data, i'll like to have a column display a grade according to the score uploaded... Also all the courses that have a score >40 should all be put into another table. Below is the loop i'm trying to make work, but it's not getting me anywhere near it.

Thanks for the help. I most appreciate it. Thanks

```
while ($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query4)) {
    if ($row4['score'] >= 70) {
        $grade = A;
    } 
    elseif ($row4['score'] >= 60) {
        $grade = B;
    }
    elseif ($row4['score'] >= 50) {
        $grade = C;
    }
    elseif ($row4['score'] >= 45) {
        $grade = D;
    }
    elseif($row4['score'] >= 40) {
        $grade = E;
    }
    elseif($row4['score'] >= 40) {
        $grade = F;
    }else {
        $grade = AR;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a CSV file and a SQL query.

Comment: Please what do you mean by "Provide a CSV file"?

Comment: `but it's not getting me anywhere near it`. Can you please expand on that. Do you get errors?

Comment: @vascowhite.... No i'm not getting errors when i put this code just after my query.

Comment: @dotman14 Unless all your grades are defined as constants, you should get a load of warnings.

Comment: @dotman14 I mean providing example of a CSV file content (comma separated values) and a SQL query that's used for `$query4` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the following should do what you are looking for. I assume that your Course ID and Student ID are in the database row, but you will need to update those if not.

```
<?php

define('GRADE_A_MIN', 70);
define('GRADE_B_MIN', 60);
define('GRADE_C_MIN', 50);
define('GRADE_D_MIN', 45);
define('GRADE_E_MIN', 40);
define('GRADE_F_MIN', 35);

$table_one_values = array(); // Used to create table for students with scores 40+
$table_two_values = array();


while ($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query4)) {
    $score = $row4['score'];
    $destination_table = 'two';

    if ( $score >= GRADE_A_MIN ) {
        $grade = 'A';
        $destination_table = 'one';

    } elseif ( $score >= GRADE_B_MIN ) {
        $grade = 'B';
        $destination_table = 'one';

    } elseif ( $score >= GRADE_C_MIN ) {
        $grade = 'C';
        $destination_table = 'one';

    } elseif ( $score >= GRADE_D_MIN ) {
        $grade = 'D';
        $destination_table = 'one';

    } elseif ( $score >= GRADE_E_MIN ) {
        $grade = 'E';
        $destination_table = 'one';

    } elseif ( $score >= GRADE_F_MIN ) {
        $grade = 'F';

    } else {
        $grade = 'AR';

    }

    $table = 'table_'.$destination_table.'_values';
    $$table[] = array(
        'course_id'     => $row4['course_id'],
        'student_id'    => $row4['student_id'],
        'score'         => $score,
        'grade'         => $grade
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some problems:

- Your `$grade` variable gets overwritten in the loop so you only will have the last value at the end. As your row contains a student number as well, you could do something like: `$grade[$row4['number']] = 'A';` to link that specific grade to a specific student number. Note that you would set your array before the loop: `$grade = array();`
- Your assignment is wrong, unless `A`, `B`, etc. are constants. It should probably be `'A'` instead of `A`, etc. So: `$grade[$row4['number']] = 'C';`, etc.

Comment: NOTE: The student number is just an ID and it doesnt have anything to do with the assignment of grades from the scores.
Thanks.

Comment: @dotman14 You will need to show the rest of your code. How many rows does `$query4` return, one per student?

Comment: www.pastebin.com/VhwMXyym .. Here is a paste of my full code. I'm using Query8 to pull the data for my grades. Hence $row8 etc.
 I have being able add another column with the grades but dont know how to put a header to it, it was added to the right. Also when i update a score the grade does not change. It still retains the grade for the initial score